# Merging/combining pre-existing docker images possible?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here's a hypothetical scenario: I have Image A, with the `task` command installed on it and Image B with `fzf`. Both images are built from `alpine`. I understand that I can do a multi-stage build like this to produce a single image with both commands on it:

```
FROM alpine as stage1
RUN apk add task 

FROM stage1 as final
RUN apk add fzf
CMD ash
```

But if Image A and Image B are already built, is there a way to merge the two?

I found this [cool project called docker-merge](https://github.com/r2d4/docker-merge) but it [throws errors.](https://github.com/r2d4/docker-merge/issues/1)

Comment: In the general case, there isn't, and if the two images aren't as tightly related as you suggest here, it's likely impossible (you couldn't merge Alpine- and Debian-based images with different system C libraries).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can be accomplished using something like `COPY from=ImageA / /`.

Here's an example Dockerfile that worked for me, combining an image with the task on it named `tw` and another, separate image with ripgrep and fzf on it name `ripgres-fzf`:

```
FROM tw

COPY --from=ripgrep-fzf / /
```

After building this Dockerfile and then running the container, the image contains all three commands (task, fzf, and ripgrep). The `/ /` was a brute force copy to ensure configuration files get carried over. Probably a better way to do that. See https://levelup.gitconnected.com/docker-multi-stage-builds-and-copy-from-other-images-3bf1a2b095e0 for a tutorial.

Comment: This isn't likely to work reliably.  Since you're copying literally everything, including the `/lib` and `/etc` trees, you're getting a kind of random mish-mash of the two images, and the conflicts in shared libraries or system files could cause hard-to-debug problems.